# A Proper Conjugate Model for A/B Test for Revenue per Click (RPC)

Tags: model, ab-test, conjugate-prior, decision-theory

What would be a proper Conjugate Posterior model for Earning / Revenue per Click in A/B test?

The data is the total number of visitors and the total revenue per day per variant (A and B).

What are the different advantages and disadvantages of the options?